# Vendor.js generated by webpack not working (Gulp watch calls webpack) / Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm working on a website where which Gulp and Webpack generate all the js files.

The problem is that the Vendor.js (that bundles **JQuery and Bootstrap** coming from the node_modules folder) generated file by webpack is not working when imported in index.html and because of that, I have to include the jquery.js and bootstrap.js files manually, which I don't want to.

When I open the generated Vendor.js file it looks like it has bootstrap.js and jquery.js in it but it doesn't work :(

Here you can see the folder structure:

[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        App: "./app/js/App.js",
        Vendor: "./app/js/Vendor.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./app/temp/scripts"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'tether', 'default'],
            // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
            Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
            Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
        })
    ]
}
```

**Vendor.js**

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
```

**scripts.js** (Gulp task)

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

gulp.task('scripts', function (callback) {
    webpack(require('../../webpack.config'), function (err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.toString());
        }
        console.log(stats.toString());
        callback();
    });
});
```

Here you have a screenshot after webpack bundles de files:
[image]

The rest of the automation works perfectly but I've been trying lots of combinations in order to make the Vendor.js file to work and I don't know what else to do.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions of how to solve this issue? In case that you need to have a look to some other file I'll share it with you.

Thanks for your help!
Rafa